# Javascript doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am using Safari 5.1 for testing, and JS doesn't work at all. In all other browsers it is working perfectly. 
This is the slide show I am implementing:[Web page](http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/12/javascript-slideshow/)
and this is the demo: [demo](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-slideshow/)

I use this slideshow as it is - I didn't change nothing, simple copy/paste.
Does someone know what's the deal with Safari?

Comment: Works fine in Safari 5.1.2 / OS X 10.7.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Preferences->Security`

Is "Enable JavaScript" unchecked for some odd reason?

Comment: Totally forgot about that. I have been loosing my mind over this for hours. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Safari Preferences, click on the Security tab, and make sure Enable JavaScript is checked.